# Can the integral of infinite geometric Brownian motions is a geometric Brownian motion?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Assume there are infinite geometric Brownian motions $S_{i}:i\in\left[0,1\right]$ where
$dS_{i}=S_{i}\left[\mu_{i}dt+\sigma_{i}dW_{i}\left(t\right)\right]$ where $d\left\langle W_{i}\left(t\right),W_{j}\left(t\right)\right\rangle =\rho_{ij}dt$. I am now considering a problem: in what conditions we have $\int_{0}^{1}x_{i}S_{i}di$ is a geometric Brownian motion? Do anyone have an idea?

Comment: You could apply to some law of large numbers for a continuum type argument.